# New the c++ object of POD(plain old data type)

Tags: c++

doing some test about the new and malloc, i expect the new
would need more assembly codes than malloc,but it is not

clang++ -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel main.cpp

new

```
int main()
{
    char *a = new char[1024];
    delete []a;

    return 0;
}
```

malloc

```
#include <cstdlib> // pulls in declaration of malloc, free

int main()
{
    char *a = (char*)malloc(1024);

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

ok, char is a POD,i guess i don't need to deal with the cost of constructor and destructor, but new do need to deal with exception(even I don't add -fno-exceptions, the result is the same), how could the assembly be same?

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:                                ## %entry
    push    RBP
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov RBP, RSP
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    xor EAX, EAX
    pop RBP
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Edit :

I change the codes again, and this time work, I have to say the compiler is so smart

new

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char *a = new char[1024];

    for(int i = 0; i != 1024; ++i){
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }

    delete []a;

    return 0;
}
```

malloc

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib> // pulls in declaration of malloc, free


int main()
{
    char *a = (char*)malloc(1024);

    for(int i = 0; i != 1024; ++i){
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

clang++ -S -O3 -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -fno-exceptions main.cpp

assembly of c

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:                                ## %entry
    push    RBP
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov RBP, RSP
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    push    R14
    push    RBX
Ltmp6:
    .cfi_offset rbx, -32
Ltmp7:
    .cfi_offset r14, -24
    mov EDI, 1024
    call    _malloc
    mov R14, RAX
    mov EBX, 1
    xor EDI, EDI
    jmp LBB0_1
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB0_2:                                 ## %for.body.for.body_crit_edge
                                        ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movsx   EDI, BYTE PTR [R14 + RBX]
    inc RBX
LBB0_1:                                 ## %for.body
                                        ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    call    _putchar
    cmp EBX, 1024
    jne LBB0_2
## BB#3:                                ## %for.end
    mov RDI, R14
    call    _free
    xor EAX, EAX
    pop RBX
    pop R14
    pop RBP
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

assembly of c++

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:                                ## %entry
    push    RBP
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov RBP, RSP
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    push    R14
    push    RBX
Ltmp6:
    .cfi_offset rbx, -32
Ltmp7:
    .cfi_offset r14, -24
    mov EDI, 1024
    call    __Znam
    mov R14, RAX
    mov EBX, 1
    xor EDI, EDI
    jmp LBB0_1
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB0_2:                                 ## %for.body.for.body_crit_edge
                                        ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movsx   EDI, BYTE PTR [R14 + RBX]
    inc RBX
LBB0_1:                                 ## %for.body
                                        ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    call    _putchar
    cmp EBX, 1024
    jne LBB0_2
## BB#3:                                ## %for.end
    test    R14, R14
    je  LBB0_5
## BB#4:                                ## %delete.notnull
    mov RDI, R14
    call    __ZdaPv
LBB0_5:                                 ## %delete.end
    xor EAX, EAX
    pop RBX
    pop R14
    pop RBP
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

c++ version are calling the assembly of new and delete, before delete the buffer.
assembly of c++ check the pointer is point to nullptr or not, if yes, don't delete
the buffer;else delete the buffer.

Comment: Why would the `new` version even need to deal with exceptions?  The compiler could conceivably optimize away the whole thing, since (1) you're using the built-in allocator and (2) you never actually *use* the array you get back, except to `delete[]` it.

Comment: @cHao: It did optimize everything away.

Comment: @rici: Yeah, i noticed after actually reading the assembler code.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assembly code looks like it's not actually doing anything.  The compiler detected that you weren't doing anything important inside main and optimized out everything except "return 0".  You might try disabling optimizations or printing the value of the pointer a.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you specified no-execptions on your command line, its not surprising that the code is the same.  Look at the difference in assembly between -fno-exceptions and exceptions enabled.

Comment: sorry, I just edited the post, even without -fno-exceptions the result is the same.Besides, which line related malloc or new?

Comment: @StereoMatching: None.  The assembly code basically means `int main() { return 0; }`.